# ImageView not appearing when button clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout

I created a small practice app which changes the image on-screen when the buttonNext is clicked. However, neither the image nor button does anything. Everything in my MainActivity looks normal for an onClickListener setup and I followed various guides to create a layout which works. But, I'm not sure why it looks so weird and does not work in the emulator.

Here is the MainActivity code I wrote so far:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setListener()
}

private fun changeImage(view: View) {
    when (view.id) {
        R.id.goodMorning -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gm1)
        R.id.goodMorning -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gm2)

        else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
    }
}

private fun setListener() {
    val goodMorning = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.goodMorning)
    val buttonNext = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.buttonNext)

    fun setListener(){

        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(goodMorning, buttonNext)

        for (item in clickableViews){
            item.setOnClickListener() { changeImage(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the layout xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/goodMorning"
    android:layout_width="404dp"
    android:layout_height="562dp"
    android:contentDescription="@android:string/no"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.428"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.365"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/gm1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    style="@style/twoButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/buttonNext"
    android:textSize="@dimen/box_text_size"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonBack"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonBack" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDownload"
    style="@style/twoButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/buttonDownload"
    android:textSize="@dimen/box_text_size"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonBack"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonBack"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="@string/buttonBack"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/box_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/goodMorning"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.718" />
```

This is what the app looks like in Pixel 2:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have `fun setListener()` defined within an outer `fun setListener()`. The inner one is never called, so its code is not executed. Promote the code within the inner function to the outer one and delete the inner function. Do that and you will see progress.

Comment: I understand. However, only one of the two images appear.

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
private fun changeImage(view: View) {
        val goodMorning = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.goodMorning)
        
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.buttonBack -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gm1)
            R.id.buttonNext -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gm2)

            else -> goodMorning.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }

    private fun setListener() {
        val buttonNext = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.buttonNext)
        val buttonBack = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.buttonBack)

        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(buttonBack, buttonNext)

        for (item in clickableViews){
            item.setOnClickListener() { changeImage(it) }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but, it does not work - none for the images appear now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix the issue:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val nextButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonNext)
    nextButton.setOnClickListener() { changeImage() }

}

private fun changeImage() {

    // Shift through all available images
    val imageOptions: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.morningImages)

    val drawableResources = when (imageOptions) {
        buttonNext -> R.drawable.gm1
        else -> R.drawable.gm2
    }

    imageOptions.setImageResource(drawableResources)
        // Repeat function needed
    }
}
```

You are better off creating the clickListener at the beginning with onCreate because you will not have to create another private function which can make this issue more confusing than it really is.

Create a new variable within the changeImage function to find the ImageView. After that, make another variable called to create a when block to shift through the images available and end it with an else statement to avoid creating an error.

Set the imageResource to drawableResources so the images appear on-screen when requested.

Note: a repeat function is needed to shift through the images again once the user goes through all of them.